# Progress bars with text on the leff - bootstrap

Tags: html, css

my question is: how can i do the progress bars loking like thats below. I'm using bootstrap and i have 2 columns 4/8. Thanks for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcNd5.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need customize the theme default from bootstrap, may can help this section.
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

after download your custom theme and redefined